# MongoDB - rejecting records with $lookup on a value from the $lookup record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get all invoices based on duedates - AND based on the status from the booking table.

I want invoices where booking.status < 5

I do NOT want invoices where booking.status >= 5

This is my aggregate:

```
db.getCollection('invoice').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            dueDate: {$gte: 1483596800},
            dueDate: {$lte: 1583596800}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "booking",
            localField: "bookingId",
            foreignField: "_id",    
            as: "booking"       
        }   
    }
])
```

And here are the tables....

```
table invoice
{
    "_id" : "IKUU",
    "bookingId" : "AAAAA",
    "dueDate" : 1489470468,
    "invoiceLines" : [ 
        {
            "lineText" : "Rent Price",
            "amountPcs" : "7 x 2071",
            "amountTotal" : 14497
        }, 
        {
            "lineText" : "Discount",
            "amountPcs" : "",
            "amountTotal" : -347
        } 
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "1NYRO",
    "bookingId" : "BBBBB",
    "dueDate" : 1489471351,
    "invoiceLines" : [ 
        {
            "lineText" : "Reservation / Booking fee",
            "amountPcs" : "1 x 2000",
            "amountTotal" : 2000
        }
    ]
}


table booking
{
    "_id" : "AAAAA",
    "checkin" : 1449756800,
    "price" : 5000,
    "status" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : "BBBBB",
    "checkin" : 1449756800,
    "price" : 6000,
    "status" : 5
}
```

I tried putting some $match{booking.status: {$lt: 5}} but I cant get it to work.

The result should be the invoice with "bookingId" : "AAAAA".

Comment: If anyone say $filter - then what about when you do stuff like this and $group invoices to make a $sum?

Comment: The output of lookup stage is an array. You've to $unwind array before $match stage. Add `{$unwind:"$booking"}` between lookup and match stage. Now you've mentioned filter so you should  use $filter with condition to filter booking array  followed by $unwind of booking array and $group to calculate $sum and $push to recreate booking array. It all depends on what you want to do after lookup stage.

Comment: @Veeram Looks like Pandas solution worked. Soon I will get to a really complex aggregate so I will try using your suggestions.  So  $unwind will unwind an array turning it into a list of one record pr array element. And $push will put it back into the array of elements?

Comment: Yeah below answer will work if you've array with single value after lookup. You've to unwind the array for multiple values to apply any filter/sort/group. You put them back into array using $group with either $addToSet or $push accumulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check for another match for booking status after $lookup like below

```
db.getCollection('invoice').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            dueDate: {$gte: 1483596800},
            dueDate: {$lte: 1583596800}
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "booking",
            localField: "bookingId",
            foreignField: "_id",    
            as: "booking"       
        }   
    },
     {
        $match: {
            "booking.status": {$lt: 5},

        }
    }
])
```

Comment: thanks!! I didnt know you could do $match on the $lookup fields after the lookup.  It works perfectly!!  Even in $group :-)